# Using linq to retrieve distinct dates

Tags: c#

Hi I'm having trouble retrieving distinct dates from a database. In this database I have several events on any particular day and results show a list of events with the same date / 'StartDate' field. How could I retrieve just the distinct days. I've tried:

```
ICollection result;
result= client.GetEventInstances().Select(x => x.StartDate).Distinct();
```

Comment: What is it you are having trouble with?

Comment: What's the data? What do you expect to see? What do you actually see?

Comment: can you please clarify this part. _In this database I have several events on any particular day and results show a list of events with the same date / 'StartDate' field_

Comment: Does StartDate contain time of day information as well as the date?

Comment: ICollection result;
result= client.GetEventInstances().Select(x => x.StartDate.Date).Distinct(); might be helpfull

Comment: Do you want to get *only* the date part of the `StartDate` property?

Comment: I expect to see just one distinct date along with just the first event for that date only

Comment: What does `GetEventInstances()` return? Is it an `IQueryable` or just a plain list?

Answer (score 0):

> I expect to see just one distinct date along with just the first event for that date only.

Then you need to group on the events and get the first item out of every date:

```
client.GetEventInstances()
    .GroupBy(k => k.StartDate.Date)
    .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.First())
```

Comment: This will likely fail if `GetEventInstances()` is an `IQueryable` from something like entity framework.

Comment: Any suggestions? @DavidG

Comment: You could select `StartDate.Year`, `StartDate.Month` and `StartDate.Day` or use `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime`

Comment: thanks, for the code, but that giving me the following error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: You should use a dictionary instead of a collection since it is grouped. Try to use `var` and see the exact type coming out.

Comment: I do you mean declare : IDictionary  result;

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to search and find a solution for my needs, it wont suit everyone of course. Thanks for the time people gave me on this, always appreciated

```
ICollection<EventInstance> result;
   result = client.GetEventInstances();

    IEnumerable<EventInstance> distinctDate = result
             .GroupBy(e => e.StartDate.Date)
             .Select(group => group.First());
```